# Get levels (contour) of a scalar field (Matplotlib / Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I'm wondering how can I get the vertices of each level of a contour plot.

For example, I have this plot:

[image]

Which has, I guess, more than 10 levels.

I'm trying to get the vertices of each one of them.

So far, I have this piece of code:

```
def iso_contours(scalar_fields):
    for scalar_field in scalar_fields:
        cs = plt.contour(scalar_field)
        paths = cs.collections[0].get_paths()
        print len(path)
        for path in paths:
            # Get vertices
```

However, I'm getting just one path. How is the properly way to achieve what I would like to?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `path.vertices`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 5, 100), np.linspace(0, 5, 100))
f = x ** y
g = y ** x
cs = plt.contour(x, y, (f - g))
for collection in cs.collections:
    paths = collection.get_paths()
    for path in paths:
        print(path.vertices.shape)

plt.show()
```

yields

```
(7, 2)
(28, 2)
(51, 2)
(172, 2)
(154, 2)
(51, 2)
(28, 2)
(7, 2)
```

[image]

Comment: My print is giving me 1. This is what I'm not getting. :/  Should I pass this [0] parameter to the contour function?

Comment: My mistake; you need to iterate over `cs.collections` to collect all the paths.